# Why can't I connect to my AWS Redshift Serverless cluster from my laptop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I've set up a Redshift Serverless cluster w/ a workgroup and a namespace.

I turned on the "Publicly Accessible" option

I've created an inbound rule for the `5439` port w/ Source set to `0.0.0.0/0`

I've created an IAM credential for access to Redshift

I ran `aws config` and added the keys

But when I run

```
aws redshift-data list-databases --cluster-identifier default --database dev --db-user admin --endpoint http://default.530158470050.us-east-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com:5439/dev
```

I get this error:

```
Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "http://default.XXXXXX.us-east-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com:5439/dev".
```

In Node, when trying to use the `AWS.RedshiftDataClient` to do the same thing, I get this:

```
{
  code: 'TimeoutError',
  path: null,
  host: 'default.XXXXXXX.us-east-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com',
  port: 5439,
  localAddress: undefined,
  time: 2022-07-09T02:20:47.397Z,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'default.XXXXXX.us-east-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you turn on the **Public Accessible** option? See: [Creating a publicly accessible Amazon Redshift Serverless instance and connecting to it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/serverless-connecting.html#serverless-publicly-accessible)

Comment: Yes. I did this as well. Should've mentioned that in the question. I'll add it.

Comment: I had the same issue as you, I went into my VPC settings and disabled the CIDR that was associated with my IP address. Also make sure you have an internet gateway setup with a route table that accepts inbound traffic on 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 2):

What Security Group and VPC have you configured for your Redshift Serverless Cluster?

Make sure the Security Group allows traffic from "My Ip" so that you can reach the VPC.

If it is not enough, check the cluster is installed on public subnets (an Internet Gateway should be attached to the VPC and the route tables route traffic to it eventually + "Publicly Accessible" option enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
My security group inbound rule did not have 'My IP'. After adding that it started working.